# Sql Inner joins not giving desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to join three tables. The query works fine when I join two tables
`TBLBPVMASTER` AND `TBLBPVDETAILS` on the basis of `bpvid` but when I combine `TableCheque` list with these two tables I get results but not as desired.

For example `TBLBPVMaster` Contains one record against `BPVID` , `TBLBPVDETAILS` contains two records against `BPVID` and `chequelist` contains two record against `BPVCODE`. Now I want to combine these three tables so that the resultant query should produce two rows. The following query produces 4 rows:

```
SELECT TBLBPVMaster.*,TBLBPVDetails.*,TBLChequeList.*
FROM   TBLBPVDetails 
       INNER JOIN TBLBPVMaster 
       ON TBLBPVDetails.BPVId = TBLBPVMaster.BPVId 
       INNER JOIN TBLChequeList 
       ON TBLBPVMaster.BPVCode = TBLChequeList.BankVoucherCode
WHERE  TBLBPVMaster.BPVId=57
```

**Output:**

```
    BPVId   DateOfPayment   SubSubsidaryAccountId   Description BPVCode TotalAmount BPVId   SubSubsidaryAccountId   Amount  Description BankVoucherCode ChequeNo    ChequeDate  PaidTo  ChequeAmount
    57      2015-03-12       1-101-1001-10001       KJSKLDJDSKL  BPV-57   2000       57     1-101-1002-10002        1000     lskdsj     BPV-57            1887      2015-03-10  kdfjhdfj    19889
    57      2015-03-12       1-101-1001-10001       KJSKLDJDSKL  BPV-57   2000       57     1-101-1001-10004        1000     dlksjkl    BPV-57            1887      2015-03-10  kdfjhdfj    19889
    57      2015-03-12       1-101-1001-10001       KJSKLDJDSKL  BPV-57   2000       57     1-101-1002-10002        1000     lskdsj     BPV-57            1878      2015-03-10  kjhdk       8787
    57      2015-03-12       1-101-1001-10001       KJSKLDJDSKL  BPV-57   2000       57     1-101-1001-10004        1000     dlksjkl    BPV-57            1878      2015-03-10  kjhdk       8787
```

Comment: `when i combine TableCheque list with these two tables i get results but not as desired..` what is the desired output and what you gettting right now ?

Comment: as i explained  the desired output should give two rows of cheque list on the basis of BPVCODE beacuse it contains two rows against that bpv code but the query above gives me 4 rows.

Comment: Can you include sample data of the tables and the desired output illustration.

Comment: I guess `inner join` to the third table will do the job

Comment: i cant upload any picture right now i don't have enough reputation

Comment: how we suppose to help if we dont know what you are after ?

Comment: no it does not do the job @AmeyaDeshpande i have tried it already

Comment: Spacing will do. 
Column1    Column2    Column3

Comment: 4 rows is exactly what one would expect, given your data and joins. You have a row which you are joining to 2 others in one table, and 2 rows in another table. Hence you will get 2 * 2 = 4 rows. Can you explain why you are expecting 2 rows? It sounds like you think one record in TBLChequeList should correspond to one record in TBLBVDetails, meaning you would get two rows in total, but how do you think these records would be linked?

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028587/how-to-get-sumcol2-as-somename-col2col3-sumcol2-as-somename1-for-the-some) how the test data included in question and try to do the same.

Comment: If all the rows match, why are you using outer join? I would also recommend using left outer joins instead of right ones, just because it's a lot simpler to use because the order is from top down in the sql, not from bottom up.

Comment: @Tanner i tried by copying the result but how to format it while pasting in the question?

Comment: @Tanner posted ! and thank you so much for every ones response !

Comment: @Tanner thankyou for formating Now see here cheuqe no 1887 and 1878 is repeating. how to solve this

Comment: Is there any more common column between `TBLBPVDetails` and `TBLChequeList ` to know which `cheque id ` belongs to which `SubSubsidaryAccountId  `

Comment: your `SubSubsidaryAccountId` and `description` has different values per row, so either remove them from the query of take one of the values and group the results.

Comment: "cheuqe no 1887 and 1878 is repeating" - yes, of course, because they are matched against different records in another table. Could you show a complete output indicating which fields come from which table? I am missing key values in your output (`BPVId` should be there _twice_, as should `BPVCode` )

Comment: @oerkelens alright i will post it again with all columns :D  but you have to fromat it !!  beacuse i deont know how to format while pasting in question

Comment: @Tanner please format it again for mee !! thankyou :)

Comment: What data do you expect to be in the 2 rows you expect. 'not as desired' seems a bit odd. The query just gives a fine result, it is exactly what your query. I guess if you want 2 rows, you should choose what row of TBLBPVMaster must be joined.

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil : Would you tell me the logic for using right join on `TableCheque` ?

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil just click edit and add spaces until the values line up with the headers, i'm not going to edit it again

Comment: @KhurramAli i have change it to inner join but still does not works!

Comment: Your 4 records are each unique. Simple question: which records do you not want to see, and why?

Comment: i don't want  cheque no to be repeated ! simple answer

Comment: No, that is not an answer. Which of the four lines do you want to see, which do you not want to see? There are two lines with 19889, but they have a different `Description`. Now, which of your four lines do you want to see? You can not choose a field, you have to choose records!

Comment: i want first two rows up to description and with these two rows i want chequeListTable attched Both rows different cheque nos ! total 2 rows

Comment: You have two descriptions, two cheque nos. That makes four combinations. Which two do you want?

Comment: you have (1)lskdsj+19889,(2)lskdsj+8787, (3)dlksjkl+19889, (4) dlksjkl+8787. So, do you want 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 1 and 4, 2 and 3, 2 and 4 or 3 and 4?

Comment: you have two rows in second and third table, so the result will be 4 rows, easy way to get desire output its to do group by on your e.g Amount,paid to or Description to get two unique rows as result.

Comment: @oerkelens i want 1 and 4

Comment: Great, then you just have to figure out how to link the data in those records to each other. Obviously, BPVCode/BankVoucherCode is not enough, because they are the same as for 2 and 3. If _you_ know why you want 1 and 4, then you have to include that in your query. If there is _nothing_ in your tables to make that link, then _that_ is your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current logic between tables TBLBPVDetails and TBLChequeList is many-to-many, so the query shows you all possible combinations 1*2*2 = 4

You should find or create a one-to-many link between tables TBLBPVDetails and TBLChequeList
Possible ways to create the link is to add a primary key for tables TBLBPVDetails and TBLChequeList, or to add a column TBLBPVDetails.ChequeNo and use the following query:

```
    SELECT TBLBPVMaster.*,TBLBPVDetails.*,TBLChequeList.*
FROM   TBLBPVDetails 
       INNER JOIN TBLBPVMaster 
       ON TBLBPVDetails.BPVId = TBLBPVMaster.BPVId 
       INNER JOIN TBLChequeList 
       ON TBLBPVDetails.ChequeNo = TBLChequeList.ChequeNo 
WHERE  TBLBPVMaster.BPVId=57
```

Second possible (but not preferable) way is to hide optional fields and supress dublicate records using distinct

```
    SELECT distinct TBLBPVMaster.*,TBLBPVDetails.BPVId, TBLBPVDetails.Amount, TBLChequeList.*
FROM   TBLBPVDetails 
       INNER JOIN TBLBPVMaster 
       ON TBLBPVDetails.BPVId = TBLBPVMaster.BPVId 
       INNER JOIN TBLChequeList 
       ON TBLBPVMaster.BPVCode = TBLChequeList.BankVoucherCode
WHERE  TBLBPVMaster.BPVId=57
```